# Facebook comments: CSS doesn't work

Tags: css, facebook, symfony1

I'm developing a website and I decided to use Facebook comments to provide commentable behaviour. But, unfortunately, I met some problems.

While trying to customize look of news page, ex. http://buchman.pcspace.pl/aktualnosci/ept-snowfest-podsumowanie-czwartego-dnia.html, I am not able to apply CSS to view: everything appears correctly in HTML source, but doesn't change view.

What's wrong?

Comment: which part of the css doesnt work? show some code and you will get a good answer

Answer (score 5):

According to [this blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/) the new fb:comments no longer supports custom CSS.

Comment: Should have heeded this advice instead of pressing on, it's absolutely correct as of March 2013

Answer (score 0):

After log research I noticed that while loading fb frame, it doesn't use css given as param.
It causes all parts don't work..